# If a communication paradigm is asynchronous, is it also time-uncoupled?

Tags: distributed-system

If a communication paradigm is asynchronous, is it also time-uncoupled? if so then are there any appropriate examples?

Comment: there are some websites which are ready to give solution but not free of charge and thats why it forced me to put in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

No.

**Time-uncoupled communication** means that the receiver(s) do not have to exist at the time the sender is sending. Sender and receiver can have independent lifetimes.

**Asynchronous communication** means that the sender does not have to wait until the receiver has received his message to proceed. The sender doesn't have to block.

What this means is that all time-uncoupled communication is asynchronous, but not vice versa. With asynchronous communication, the receiver doesn't have to meet in time with the sender, but he has to exist at the time the sender is sending. So, asynchronous communication is not time-uncoupled.

My source is Chapter 6 (Indirection communication) from this book [https://www.amazon.com/Distributed-Systems-Concepts-Design-5th/dp/0132143011](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132143011) .